# Object is not async iterable error while using @aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming and React Native

Tags: react-native, audio-streaming, amazon-transcribe

Has anyone had any luck attempting to use client-transcribe-streaming in React native?

I'm trying to stream audio from the device microphone to get a transcription from AWS. When I attempt to begin a transcription I get the error `TypeError: Object is not async iterable` even though I have an async generator handling the audio to the TranscribeStreamingClient.

Any examples I've found involve web/browser solutions using the Node.js `microphone-stream` package, but I can't find any equivalent package for React Native. The closest I've found is the `react-native-live-audio-stream`, but I'm getting an error and the AWS documentation is no help.

I do get a response returned from the `.send()` function:

```
{"$metadata": {"attempts": 1, "cfId": undefined, "extendedRequestId": undefined, "httpStatusCode": 200, "requestId": undefined, "totalRetryDelay": 0}, "SessionId": "633592f0-8ce5-487d-a67e-6c05001f7b98", "TranscriptResultStream": {"options": {"deserializer": [Function anonymous], "messageStream": [MessageDecoderStream]}}}
```

but when I dig into the the `messageDecoderStream` it contains an empty array. I've double checked to ensure audio is being captured and pushed into the `audioPayloadStream`.

I'm thoroughly confused as to why I'm getting a TypeError.

I'm stuck, I can't find any successful React Native attempts at this.

Here is the code I'm using

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values'; 
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'; 
import { TranscribeStreamingClient, StartStreamTranscriptionCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming'; 
import LiveAudioStream from 'react-native-live-audio-stream'; 
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'; 

const useTranscribeController = () => { 
  let isStarted = false; 
  let audioPayloadStream: any = []; 
  const audioStream = LiveAudioStream; 
  const client = new TranscribeStreamingClient({ 
    region: 'us-west-2', 
    credentials: { 
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
      sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, 
    }, 
  }); 
  
  const audioGenerator = async function* () {
    for await (const chunk of audioPayloadStream) {
      yield { AudioEvent: { AudioChunk: chunk } };
    } 
  }; 

  const stop = () => {
    audioPayloadStream = [];
    audioStream.stop();
    client.destroy();
    isStarted = false;
  };

  const start = async () => {
    try {
      isStarted = true;
      const command = new StartStreamTranscriptionCommand({
        LanguageCode: 'en-US',
        MediaEncoding: 'pcm',
        MediaSampleRateHertz: 44100,
        AudioStream: audioGenerator(),
      });
      const response = await client.send(command);
      console.log(response);
      if (response.TranscriptResultStream) {
        for await (const event of response.TranscriptResultStream) {
          const message = event.TranscriptEvent;
          const results = event.TranscriptEvent?.Transcript?.Results;
          results?.map(result => {
            (result.Alternatives || []).map(alternative => {
              const transcript = alternative.Items?.map(item => item.Content).join(' '); 
              console.log({ transcript });
            });
          });
        }
      } else {
        console.log('the response is undefined');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      if (isStarted) {
        stop();
      }
    } 
  }; 

  const initialize = async () => {
    const options = {
      sampleRate: 44100, 
      channels: 1, 
      bitsPerSample: 16, 
      audioSource: 6, 
      bufferSize: 1024, 
      wavFile: 'pcm.wav', 
    }; 
    
    audioStream.init(options); 
    audioStream.start(); 
    audioStream.on('data', data => { 
      audioPayloadStream.push(Buffer.from(data, 'base64')); 
      if (!isStarted && audioPayloadStream.length !== 0) {
        start(); 
      }  
    }); 
  }; 
  return { initialize }; 
}; 

export default useTranscribeController;
```

Comment: Hi, Hermes doesn't support async iterators yet (the feature is planned, but no release date yet), so for await is unsupported and produces the corresponding error message when encountered. As you know, in RN apps JS code undergoes Babel transformations which should eliminate instances of for await. - Please disable Hermes on iOS & android. It works fine!!!.